# Is there anything possible idea of 'cyclic arithmetic operation' for some specific data type?

Tags: sql-server

In integer-based data type like tinybit, smallbit, bigint, int, uint...
sometimes arithmetic overflow could be found when result is out of range of that data type.

The expression I used, 'cyclic arithmetic operation', that means,
**(-1)** 2 -> 1 -> 0 -> 255 -> 254 ... (tinybit)
or
**(+2)** 65533 -> 65535 -> 1 -> 3 ... (smallbit)
etc..

In other words, I want 0 - 1 = 255 in tinybit columns.

I know it's little awkward and everyone have avoided this kind of situation but is there anyone who have solution for this? The reason I ask is not only to avoid arithmetic overflow but also practical need. So "consider extending or changing your column data type!" will not be suitable in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying a bit mask seems to be the most straightforward way to do this:

```
SELECT -10 & 255; -- Results in 246
SELECT 513 & 255; -- Results in 1
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-operators-transact-sql

Comment: Genius solution Soukai. I really appreciate for your answer and your effort to my question. ALL CLEAR! :)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server does have a modulus operator, `%`, which might help here. Using it, you can do something like this:

```
DECLARE @inputValue INT = -1;
DECLARE @outputValue TINYINT;

DECLARE @minValue INT = 0;
DECLARE @maxValue INT = 255;
DECLARE @maxValues INT = 256;

SELECT @outputValue =
    CASE
        WHEN @inputValue < @minValue THEN @inputValue % @maxValues + @maxValues
        ELSE @inputValue % @maxValues
    END;

SELECT @outputValue; -- Results in 255
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql

Comment: Thanks Soukai. Yes, I'd considered modulo, over 255, it's okay. But could '0 - 1 = 255' be possible with modulo?

Comment: After more thought, I posted a new answer about using a bit mask instead. I'll update this one to be more complete, but the bit mask seems like a much more elegant solution.