# Finding Max value in column with condition(0 is max where 0 exists)

Tags: sql-server

A column has values of '00', '01', '02', '03', ...
I want to find out each Name's max value. But, if there is '00' exists then
max should be '00'. If isn't, max is max.

**Original**

*Name Value*

Tom | 00
Tom | 01
Tom | 02
Jane | 01
Jane | 02
Jane | 03
Jack | 00
Jack | 01

**Result**

*Name Value*

Tom | 00
Jane | 03
Jack | 00

'If' statement will be fine, but I think there must be simpler way.

Comment: Couple of `case` would handle this cleanly.

Comment: You're right shawnt.`case` also would be suitable for this situation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT Name, CASE WHEN Min(Value)='00' THEN Min(Value) 
    ELSE Max(Value) END
FROM [table1]
GROUP BY Name;
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c136b/7

Comment: Neat and nice answer. Thank you Sahi.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the value '00' exists for the person and use it if true.

If not, compute the MAX value.

```
SELECT Name, ISNULL((SELECT Value FROM [table1] t WHERE t.Name = [table1].Name AND Value = '00'), MAX(Value)) AS Value
    FROM [table1]
    GROUP BY Name;
```

You can see it live on this SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c136b/1/0

Comment: Thanks Pedro. This looks nice.

Answer (score 0):

Sample data

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
DROp TABLE #Temp

;With CTE_Temp(Name,Value)
AS
(
SELECT 'Tom' , 00   UNION ALL
SELECT 'Tom' , 01   UNION ALL
SELECT 'Tom' , 02   UNION ALL
SELECT 'Jane' , 01  UNION ALL
SELECT 'Jane' , 02  UNION ALL
SELECT 'Jane' , 03  UNION ALL
SELECT 'Jack' , 00  UNION ALL
SELECT 'Jack' , 01
)
SELECT * INTO #Temp FROm CTE_Temp
```

Try this below script

```
;WITH CTE_Final
AS
(

SELECT  Name
        ,Value
        ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PArtition BY Name ORDER By value ) AS Rnk
        ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Seq 
FROM
(
SELECT Name,
      IIF(value=0,0, MAX(Value)OVER(Partition by Name ORDER BY Value DESC)) AS Value 
From #temp
GROUP BY Name,Value
)dt
)
SELECT  Name,
        RIGHT('00'+CAST(Value AS varchar(5)),2) AS Value
FROM  CTE_Final 
    WHERE Rnk=1
    ORDER BY Name DESC
```

Result

```
    Name    Value
    -------------
    Tom     00
    Jane    03
    Jack    00
```

Comment: Though I want some 'simpler' method lol, but anyway, thanks for your answer Sreenu. Approaching with ROW_NUMBER for this kind of job is new to me. Good for study!

Answer (score 0):

I found an interesting solution thanks to Soukai in my another article.

[Is there anything possible idea of 'cyclic arithmetic operation' for some specific data type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49163545/is-there-anything-possible-idea-of-cyclic-arithmetic-operation-for-some-specif/49164177?noredirect=1#comment85334998_49164177)

```
Select Name, RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, (max((convert(int, Value) - 1) & 255) + 1) & 255), 2) as Value from Table;
```

**00** 01 02 03 04 ... 99 : 00 to be max and for others, max is max
↓'cyclic decreasing' 1
**255** 00 01 02 03 ... 98 : find 255 as max which was 00 originally, if not,
still max is max
↓'cyclic increasing' 1
**00** 01 02 03 04 ... 99 : Done.

Answer (score 0):

```
case max(case when val = '00' then '9999' else val end)
    when '9999' then '00' else max(val) end
```

or

```
case min(val) when '00' then '00' else max(val) end
```

Comment: Shorter is better. Good answer shawnt. Thank you.